# C++ Decimal Floating Point Erroneous Rounding

Tags: c++, gcc, floating-point

I am seeing some strange behavior when attempting to use libdfp in a C++ program.  Specifically, it appears as if GCC is always rounding to 8 decimal places, even when I use the 64- and 128-bit decimal types.

To test this, I created an incredibly simple test program:

```
std::decimal::decimal64 testval = 0.044575289999999997DD;
printf("Decimal float test: expected=0.044575289999999997, actual=%.16Da\n", testval);
```

Which outputs:

```
Decimal float test: expected=0.044575289999999997, actual=0.04457529000000000
```

I am fairly certain that this is not a printing problem in libdfp as I was able to trace the source and found that the number is already rounded by the first line of the printf handler.  Additionally, the printf handler will also round, however I have verified that this code is not being called.

For reference, I am building libdfp with:

```
./configure --with-backend=libdecnumber --enable-decimal-float=bid && make
```

I suspect the problem to either be in the underlying decimal float representation (BID, in my case) or the raw types being provided by GCC.  It almost looks as if everything is being rounded to the size of a 32-bit decimal float.  My host arch is x86_64 so this should all be supported natively.  Furthermore, GCC does have the corresponding `_Decimal[32|64|128]` types and `<decimal/decimal>` can be found on the system.  I am building on Fedora 25 for a native x86_64 CPU (Intel Xenon).  AFAIK, this processor does not have native decimal float support so everything is being rendered in software.

The only clue I have is that GCC does not list the `--enable-decimal-float` build option in the configuration summary:

```
$ g++ -v
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=g++
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/6.3.1/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-redhat-linux
Configured with: ../configure --enable-bootstrap --enable-languages=c,c++,objc,obj-c++,fortran,ada,go,lto --prefix=/usr --mandir=/usr/share/man --infodir=/usr/share/info --with-bugurl=http://bugzilla.redhat.com/bugzilla --enable-shared --enable-threads=posix --enable-checking=release --enable-multilib --with-system-zlib --enable-__cxa_atexit --disable-libunwind-exceptions --enable-gnu-unique-object --enable-linker-build-id --with-linker-hash-style=gnu --enable-plugin --enable-initfini-array --disable-libgcj --with-isl --enable-libmpx --enable-gnu-indirect-function --with-tune=generic --with-arch_32=i686 --build=x86_64-redhat-linux
Thread model: posix
gcc version 6.3.1 20161221 (Red Hat 6.3.1-1) (GCC)

$ g++ --version
g++ (GCC) 6.3.1 20161221 (Red Hat 6.3.1-1)
Copyright (C) 2016 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

That being said, my compiler *does* define the `_Decimal[32|64|128]` types and provides operator<< overloads for them.  I wouldn't expect these to be available at all if such support were not enabled.  I certainly shouldn't be able to compile a program using them and get *almost* valid output back.

Finally, I could see this being a problem with libdecnumber but I am just about at the limit of my current knowledge as to who manages assignment to these types.

Has anybody seen this issue before?  Failing that, has anybody build and successfully used libdfp on a similar setup?  Which piece of software controls rounding for the internal representation (as opposed to rounding for display)?

---

**EDIT**

I finally managed to get a disassembly.  It appears that the full value is being loaded into `rdx` and the `decimal64` constructor called.  The value `0x2fafd619589efa00` works out to `3436200445056317952` in decimal, which I suspect is `0.044575289999999997` represented in BID format.  I am not sure how GCC knows to used BID vs DPD as this is specified at libfdp build time, however I will leave that particular mystery for another post.

If my understanding is correct, it seems to imply that GCC is doing the rounding.  Is there anything that can be done about this other than rebuilding the compiler (which I would really like to avoid)?  I know IEEE-754 provides mechanisms to 'tune' the behavior of fp operations (including rounding mode), does GCC expose any of this to the user?

**Disassembly**

```
   │0x401180 <main(int, char**)>    push   rbp                                                                                                        │
   │0x401181 <main(int, char**)+1>  mov    rbp,rsp                                                                                                    │
   │0x401184 <main(int, char**)+4>  sub    rsp,0x30                                                                                                   │
   │0x401188 <main(int, char**)+8>  mov    DWORD PTR [rbp-0x14],edi                                                                                   │
   │0x40118b <main(int, char**)+11> mov    QWORD PTR [rbp-0x20],rsi                                                                                   │
b+ │0x40118f <main(int, char**)+15> movabs rdx,0x2fafd619589efa00                                                                                     │
   │0x401199 <main(int, char**)+25> lea    rax,[rbp-0x10]                                                                                             │
   │0x40119d <main(int, char**)+29> mov    QWORD PTR [rbp-0x28],rdx                                                                                   │
   │0x4011a1 <main(int, char**)+33> movq   xmm0,QWORD PTR [rbp-0x28]                                                                                  │
   │0x4011a6 <main(int, char**)+38> mov    rdi,rax                                                                                                    │
   │0x4011a9 <main(int, char**)+41> call   0x4012e6 <std::decimal::decimal64::decimal64(decimal64)>                                                   │
   │0x4011ae <main(int, char**)+46> mov    rax,QWORD PTR [rbp-0x10]                                                                                   │
   │0x4011b2 <main(int, char**)+50> mov    QWORD PTR [rbp-0x28],rax                                                                                   │
   │0x4011b6 <main(int, char**)+54> movq   xmm0,QWORD PTR [rbp-0x28]                                                                                  │
   │0x4011bb <main(int, char**)+59> mov    edi,0x4018e8                                                                                               │
   │0x4011c0 <main(int, char**)+64> mov    eax,0x1                                                                                                    │
   │0x4011c5 <main(int, char**)+69> call   0x400a30 <printf@plt>                                                                                      │
   │0x4011ca <main(int, char**)+74>                                         mov    eax,0x0                                                            │
   │0x4011cf <main(int, char**)+79>                                         leave                                                                     │
   │0x4011d0 <main(int, char**)+80>                                         ret                                                                       │
   │0x4011d1 <__static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int)>          push   rbp                                                                │
   │0x4011d2 <__static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int)+1>        mov    rbp,rsp                                                            │
   │0x4011d5 <__static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int)+4>────────sub    rsp,0x10───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────│
   │0x4011d9 <__static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int)+8>        mov    DWORD PTR [rbp-0x4],edi                                            │
   │0x4011dc <__static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int)+11>       mov    DWORD PTR [rbp-0x8],esi                                            │
   │0x4011df <__static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int)+14>       cmp    DWORD PTR [rbp-0x4],0x1                                            │
   │0x4011e3 <__static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int)+18>       jne    0x40120c <__static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int)+59>  │
   │0x4011e5 <__static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int)+20>       cmp    DWORD PTR [rbp-0x8],0xffff                                         │
   │0x4011ec <__static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int)+27>       jne    0x40120c <__static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int)+59>  │
   │0x4011e5 <__static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int)+20>       cmp    DWORD PTR [rbp-0x8],0xffff                                         │
   │0x4011ec <__static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int)+27>       jne    0x40120c <__static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int)+59>  │
   │0x4011ee <__static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int)+29>       mov    edi,0x60309d                                                       │
   │0x4011f3 <__static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int)+34>       call   0x400ae0 <_ZNSt8ios_base4InitC1Ev@plt>                             │
   │0x4011f8 <__static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int)+39>       mov    edx,0x4018d8                                                       │
   │0x4011fd <__static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int)+44>       mov    esi,0x60309d                                                       │
   │0x401202 <__static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int)+49>       mov    edi,0x400aa0                                                       │
   │0x401207 <__static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int)+54>       call   0x400ac0 <__cxa_atexit@plt>                                        │
```

**Complete Test Source**

```
#include <float.h>
#include <decimal/decimal>
#include <math.h>
#include <fenv.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <wchar.h>
#include <cstdlib>

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    std::decimal::decimal64 testval = 0.044575289999999997DD;
    printf("Decimal float test: expected=0.044575289999999997, actual=%.16Da\n", testval);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: What does the disassembly do?

Comment: Unfortunately, that will have to wait until tonight to check.  Is there anything in particular I should look for?

Comment: Do you realize that the 2 decimals differ in the 17th decimal place? Are you sure that decimal64 has enough precision to distinguish the 2?

Comment: If it were a precision problem I would expect to see more / less decimals (though, admittedly, not necessarily all) if I switch from 32 to 64 to 128.  However, I see the same result (rounded at the eighth place) regardless of which type I use.

Comment: Well, look to see how the literals are being loaded into registers and/or the stack. This will lead you to find out if the literals encoded with full precision in the first place, or if the precision is lost somewhere else along the way.

Comment: Edited post with full disassembly.  Questions folded into edit.